Telegram Login Widget on Native Apps - Broken fragmet
Im trying to use Telegram Login Widget on Native App made with Ionic.
Im using a InAppBrowser to open the auth page, after the Telegram Verification completes,
I get redirected to my redirectUrl link with an fragmet as addition tgAuthResult=eyJ
pZCI6NjAzNzg4ODE×NCwiZ-...
This seems like a corrupted link from telegram. Is there a way to clean the fragmet and decode it to get the preferd JSON from Telegram ?
